# JavaScript Toggle Show/Hide Responsive Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been stuck on this particular problem. I would like to use a toggle menu for mobile widths on a website that I'm working on. Basically, it works nicely as I can show you on this [CodePen](http://cdpn.io/pJkbi).

The code for showing/hiding the menu via a toggle button with JavaScript works below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Menu Open Seasame Action    
  $('.site-nav-btn').click(function() {
  $('.site-nav ul').slideToggle('fast');
  $(this).find('span:hidden').show().siblings().hide();
});

  //Hide site-nav content.    
  $(".site-nav ul").hide();
});
```

My problem is that I would like to hide the toggle button and the toggle function when the width exceeds say, 480 pixels wide but keep the site-nav ul visible. I've been trying to do this via this code combined with the one above, and somehow it just doesn't work.

```
$(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 480) {
      $('.site-nav-btn').css('display','none');
      $('.site-nav ul').show();
      }
  else {
      $('.site-nav-btn').css('display','block');
      $('.site-nav ul').hide();
      }
  });
```

I'm not really that proficient in JavaScript so if anyone could point out why it didn't work alongside the solutions that would really be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach your checking function to `$(window).resize()` and fix the selectors. See [this fork of your CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uvCbg).

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. This helped me immeasurably.